# Parent account access for a user who owns child account record

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

we have a requirement to provide access to  the parent account for any user who owns the child account record. We are using parent-child relation of of account record.

Unfortunately, If a user owns the child record SFDC doesn't provision automatic access to parent account record.

The Options I am considering are

1- Trigger on account to locate parent and grand parent and add the user on account team

2- Write Apex sharing records for parent and grand parent.

I am leaning towards #1 because account team can be reportable and manageable through  screens but not  the Apex sharing.

Is there any option to accomplish this sharing through configuration and without wring code ?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike master-detail relationships, Accounts in a hierarchy don't have an implicit sharing model. Therefore, I think the only options for you are the two you outlined.

There is one alternative worth mentioning and that is Territory Management. The idea with territory management is to tie account and/or opportunities into defined territories. This may be overkill for what you're suggesting but I thought I'd throw it out there nonetheless:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_def.htm&language=en

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks @greenstork and you are right the company is not ready to look into territory management given the overhead and most importantly the current business model is not well suited for territory management.